# Solr(5.3.1) Spell check vs Suggest

Tags: solr

All, Forgive me I just work with `Solr` for a couple of days. 
As I knew . both `SpellCheck` module and `Suggest` module can do the auto-completion in the solr. So what is the difference between them ? In what case I should use one of them , not another? I tried to search it in the internet. But didn't found anything telling about it. Did I miss something ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do similar task: **provide user with similar terms**.

But `Suggester` is more powerful, there is a `SuggestComponent` that supports all of the lookup implementations available in Lucene.

So, use `Suggester` if u want to build a power suggestion service to user.

Check [solr reference](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Suggester) for details.

Comment: +1 Hi Eric , It seems the spell check can do more configuration about the result. like `accuracy`. Right ?

Comment: From my view, in `spell check` you are doing configuration to customize the single implementation. But with `suggester`, u are choosing between multiple implementations providing by lucene. Also, sometimes we write the suggestion service out of lucene, e.g by querying `RDMS` with `like`, I think it depends on your actual requirement & data. As the solr reference says: `Although it is possible to use the Spell Checking functionality to power autosuggest behavior, Solr has a
dedicated SuggestComponent designed for this functionality.`, I believe that is a recommendation for `suggester`.

Comment: Good explain! Thanks Eric