# Understand Solr suggester module

Tags: solr

All, If I asked a dump question, please forgive me I am just a newbie of Solr.

The reason I ask this question is I was trying to add `auto-completion` function in my web site. Currently I just followed `Solr reference` . and tried to build the function(auto-completion) on the `Suggest` module (although I knew `Spell Check` can do the same things). and it works well.

But what makes me confused is Why need Suggest module?

The [Reference](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Suggester) just said :

> The SuggestComponent in Solr provides users with automatic suggestions
>   for query terms. You can use this to implement a powerful auto-suggest
>   feature in your search application.

In my understanding , I think the functions of Solr (select, query, suggest, spellcheck)do the same thing. All of them just search index fields in the Solr and return the result. and all the result are from one or more fields in the `Solr`. I didn't see any specific reason I `have to` choose this or not others.

**In other words, For the auto-completion function. I can use any of them (select, query, suggest, spellcheck) to make it.**

I think my problem I didn't understand these module well. Could someone please show me some light on it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solr(5.3.1) Spell check vs Suggest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34459375/solr5-3-1-spell-check-vs-suggest)

Comment: @YoungHobbit updated it . Please help to review it .thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement auto-complete feature using any of them (select, query, suggest, spellcheck). Because underneath they all access the indexes (inverted indexes) for searching the queries. The data structure to store the indexes for quick responses is `Trie`.

Even Solr suggest component creates separate dictionary from the configured `field` and `suggestAnalyzerFieldType`. When a request a comes to suggest dictionary then how the lookup should be performed depends on the `lookupImpl` configured. When you return the response in the suggestion, you can send only the `field` and one more field as `payload`.

Where as `/select` and `/query` acts as more of an REST endpoint for querying/searching the terms into the indexes. You can fetch any number of fields in the response. Also you can build complex query which access the indexes of multiple fields.